# Need assistance with design of website search using sql query

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, sql

I have been trying to come up with a way design a webpage to allow users to make selections on a webpage and then query those selections in a database and returned to the user.

For example, my database is a list of houses. The data base table is set up something like this:

```
Country    Region     State      City       House
   1          1         1          1          A
   1          1         1          1          B
   1          1         1          2          C
   1          1         1          2          D
   1          1         1          3          E
   1          2         2          4          G
   1          2         3          5          H
   1          3         4          6          I
   1          4         5          7          J
```

From the search bar, I want the user to be able to say show me any and all houses in region 2, any houses in state 3, and any houses in city 1.

In this example, the data base query would come back with houses G,H,A, and B. The order of the search and results don't really matter right now.

Is something like this even possible? I have considered using check boxes on the website but ideally I would rather just have one search bar using autocomplete (jquery) where each entry has specific values tied to it. These values are what would be passed to the search query as variables.

Comment: Just to make sure ... Are you asking for design/UI/UX or for SQL advice?

Comment: I need to assign each search term those 4 variables and pass those variables over to sql. I assumed I would use cases for the sql query for each search term that has been selected by the user.

Comment: The table is way more readable in a fixed space format than otherwise. Keep an eye in the preview before saving. `=]`

Comment: Why would it also output House I?

Comment: Typo, my bad. Thanks for catching.

Answer (score 0):

you could use comma separator as when you use google maps, then split the content of the search box using the comma delimiter and then you will have the 3 parameters that you need.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be `<select>` elements in a `<form method="GET" action="somefile.php">`, and then within the file somefile.php retrieving the `$_GET` values that the user posted on the form in the `<select>` elements and then generating SQL queries appropriately to retrieve the data.

The answer is yes, it is possible, but you're asking a lot if you're asking for someone to do it for you.

Comment: Yeah, I don't need someone to do it for me. I was just looking for some guidance on the best method of doing it. I was using the select and get methods but I couldn't figure out how to search for more than just one term at a time. Either searching only city or searching only regions. I was trying to do all at once based on user selections.

Answer (score 0):

As @khanahk said, you could use select boxes.

> I couldn't figure out how to search for more than just one term at a time.

You could have multiple select boxes, such as four or five on one line, with a submit button to search using the paramters selected by those select boxes.

Or you could do something really cool with a search box that uses keywords to separate the different type of search, ex.) `House-a IN region-1`

I'd take a look at the following link:
http://www.arroyocode.com/client-side-keyword-search-with-jquery-ui-autocomplete-and-asp-net-mvc-4

Comment: That looks pretty cool. I might look into something like that.